# Azure DevOps pipeline: Azure Copy Files step V4 error - can't find the specified folder

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am tying to deploy static version of storybook to Azure Cloud Storage blob container using Azure DevOps pipeline.

Since the image is sometimes more descriptive:
[image: what is the absolute path]

The SourcePath (or Source in image above) needs to be an absolute path to file/folder you want to copy to blob.
I referred to:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/edit/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopyV4/README.md
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops
and various other sources.
No matter what predefined variable I try to use, I always see the same error:

`failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: cannot scan the path \\?\D:\a\1\dist-storybook, please verify that it is a valid.`

And this is what I tried so far:

```
  - task: AzureFileCopy@4
    inputs:
#      SourcePath: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/dist-storybook'
#      SourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist-storybook'
      SourcePath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/dist-storybook'
#      SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist-storybook'
      azureSubscription: 'xxx'
      Destination: 'AzureBlob'
      storage: 'xxx'
      ContainerName: 'storybook'
```

Before you go with the comments to check if dist-storybook folder exists and whether I verified.

Yes it exists. Before I tried Azure File Copy v4 task I was using `AzureRmWebAppDeployment` task with this param: `packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist-storybook'` (which deploys to Azure App Service [but in case of Storybook it's an overkill, because generated Storybook consists of static files and doesn't require the server to run]) and it was deploying Storybook successfully. So the `dist-storybook` is properly generated in previous step in the pipeline.

Anyone has any clues?

UPDATE:

After receiving some help on Microsoft Developer Forum:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1203833/azure-file-copy-source-requires-absolute-path.html

I started using v3 (AzureFileCopy@3) of the task with the `$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)` predefined system variable (which I already used unsuccessfully with v4 [AzureFileCopy@4])

This is the full task:

```
  - task: AzureFileCopy@3
    inputs:
      SourcePath: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/dist-storybook/*'
      azureSubscription: 'xxx'
      Destination: 'AzureBlob'
      storage: 'xxx'
      ContainerName: 'storybook'
```

Now I get this error:

```
2020-09-30T09:19:03.1646485Z ##[section]Starting: AzureFileCopy
2020-09-30T09:19:03.1870156Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-30T09:19:03.1871285Z Task         : Azure file copy
2020-09-30T09:19:03.1872336Z Description  : Copy files to Azure Blob Storage or virtual machines
2020-09-30T09:19:03.1873312Z Version      : 3.175.2
2020-09-30T09:19:03.1874422Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-09-30T09:19:03.1876194Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy
2020-09-30T09:19:03.1877411Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-30T09:19:06.0053519Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\modules\azurerm_6.13.1\AzureRM\6.13.1\AzureRM.psd1 -Global
2020-09-30T09:19:29.9367823Z ##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process
2020-09-30T09:19:31.1812482Z ##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
2020-09-30T09:19:32.3448727Z ##[command]Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud
2020-09-30T09:19:34.2134374Z ##[command] Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId 5a6f9ac1-3fc5-4ecc-9909-7c1f7be55b1f -TenantId ***
2020-09-30T09:19:41.8630229Z Uploading files from source path: 'D:\a\1\s\dist-storybook\*' to storage account: 'stdesignsystemdevuksouth' in container: 'storybook' with blob prefix: ''
2020-09-30T09:19:41.9074144Z ##[command] & "AzCopy\AzCopy.exe" /Source:"D:\a\1\s\dist-storybook\*" /Dest:"https://stdesignsystemdevuksouth.blob.core.windows.net/storybook" /@:"D:\a\_temp\9a9dd952-202a-4851-91ed-e27a062f8f4a" /XO /Y /SetContentType /Z:"AzCopy" /V:"AzCopy\AzCopyVerbose_a1f6be33-1856-4036-98e1-d6c9c5a151af.log" /S
2020-09-30T09:19:42.8784330Z [2020/09/30 09:19:42][ERROR] Error parsing source location "D:\a\1\s\dist-storybook\*": Failed to enumerate directory D:\a\1\s\dist-storybook\*\ with file pattern *. The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003) For more details, please type "AzCopy /?:Source" or use verbose option /V.
2020-09-30T09:19:43.1065203Z ##[command]Disconnect-AzureRmAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2020-09-30T09:19:43.9220995Z ##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2020-09-30T09:19:44.4426511Z ##[error]Upload to container: 'storybook' in storage account: 'stdesignsystemdevuksouth' with blob prefix: '' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.' For more info please refer to https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme
2020-09-30T09:19:44.5187191Z ##[section]Finishing: AzureFileCopy
```

Comment: Is it possible to share your complete definition? Can you please run 'dir dist-storybook /s /p' in Command line task, then share the debug log here(set **system.debug** to **true**)?

Comment: After do further confirmation, the error you encountered mostly occurred if folder does not exists under your specified path. Or have no permission to access this folder. You can share the above log so that I can help you locate the correct configuration.

Comment: Hi @MerlinLiang-MSFT - I got sidetracked into other things at work for the whole day yesterday - I will be investigating further today on the pipeline and will post any findings here. I updated my question

Comment: I noticed your updates. If you'd like to copy the entire contents of **dist-storybook** folder to azure blob, just need to specify the **SourcePath** as **$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/dist-storybook** Feel free to let me know if this can get you unblock

Comment: Hi Merlin - I have the whole pipeline working. It is a bit complicated what was going on in there, so I need to find some time and will update my question or simply write a lengthy answer. Bottom line is: Azure File Copy task only works on windows vm. When I changed the vm in the pipeline from ubuntu to windows, the dist-storybook folder was no longer generated in the Build step but was failing without error. After I confirmed the contents of the directory where the pipeline runs and the fact there were no longer /dist and /dist-storybook folders in there I was able to fix the issue.

Comment: ohh, that’s great. At least, you knew the issue cause now. Per my opinion, you can construct your pipeline with 2 jobs if the dist-storybook folder will not be generated in windows. One is generating destination folder with ubuntu agent, and another is copy them to azure blob.